# How to prevent WebView2(Edge based) to open a new window

Tags: c#, winforms, webview2

Inside Webview2 when I open a new tab, a new window outside WindowsForms is open. I want to prevent this window to Open, how can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop webview2 from opening new browser window rather than inside the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66002331/how-to-stop-webview2-from-opening-new-browser-window-rather-than-inside-the-brow)

Comment: no, Because It can't handle with pop up windows, only with new tabs.

Comment: There is [a good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73841289/3193470) to make your app deals with new tabs like **real browsers**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can handle [`CoreWebView2.NewWindowRequested`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.newwindowrequested?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.705.50&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) to decide about new window

- To completely suppress the popup, set `e.Handled = true;`
- To show the popup content in the same window, set `e.NewWindow = (CoreWebView2)sender;`
- To open in another specific instance, set `e.NewWindow` to the other `CoreWebView2` instance.

For example:

```
//using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core;
//using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms;

WebView2 webView21 = new WebView2();
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webView21.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    this.Controls.Add(webView21);
    webView21.Source = new Uri("Https://stackoverflow.com");
    await webView21.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
    webView21.CoreWebView2.NewWindowRequested += CoreWebView2_NewWindowRequested;
}

private void CoreWebView2_NewWindowRequested(object sender,
    CoreWebView2NewWindowRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    e.NewWindow = (CoreWebView2)sender;
    //e.Handled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To complement @Reza answer I was having this exact problem in VB.Net but all the answers were for C# so im going to post it in here if anyone else needs it.

First make sure to import this:

```
Imports Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core
Imports Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms
```

And then add this 2 events just replace wVBrowser with your Webview2 control name.

```
Private Sub wVBrowser_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(sender As Object, e As CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs) Handles wVBrowser.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted
            AddHandler wVBrowser.CoreWebView2.NewWindowRequested, AddressOf CoreWebView2_NewWindowRequested
        End Sub
Private Sub CoreWebView2_NewWindowRequested(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2NewWindowRequestedEventArgs)
            e.Handled = True
        End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Just be careful about where you register the `WebView.CoreWebView2.NewWindowRequested` event..

I tried to use `Browser.Initialized` event in which handler I would register this event handler but that event is **never raised**.

I had to use `Browser.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted` and now everything works **just fine**..