# e.NewWindow = (CoreWebView2)sender still results in a separate instance

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, webview2

I want to navigate to the URL rather than it opening a separate instance.
No matter what I do it still opens another instance of WebView2.

```
private void CoreWebView2_NewWindowRequested(object sender,
            CoreWebView2NewWindowRequestedEventArgs e)
        {
            //e.NewWindow = webView21.CoreWebView2;
            e.NewWindow = (CoreWebView2)sender;
            //e.Handled = true;
        }
```

[here's the original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66191200/how-to-prevent-webview2edge-based-to-open-a-new-window), what do I need to do for it to handle the new window request?

Answer (score 5):

To receive a notification when a new **Popup Windows** is requested, subscribe to the the [NewWindowRequested](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.newwindowrequested) of CoreWebView2.

The event is raised when there's a request to generate a Popup. Clicking a link that just cause the Browser to navigate to a different URI doesn't raise the event (no popup).
A new Popup Window can be requested if the User clicks the `Open link in new window`  (sic) option of the standard ContextMenu provided by the Browser.
Or if the Web Page generates one without user intervention.

Unfortunately, the [e.IsUserInitiated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2newwindowrequestedeventargs.isuserinitiated) property is always `true`, so you may have a hard time determining (without injecting JavaScripts) whether the popup should be blocked (in case you want to, that is).

When a new Window is requested, you can block it indiscriminately setting **`e.Handled = true`**

If you want to open the new Window URI to the same Window, you can specify either:

```
e.Handled = true;
e.NewWindow = (CoreWebView2)sender;
// or  
e.Handled = true;
((CoreWebView2)sender).Navigate(e.Uri);
```

---

**Sample WebView2 main handler Form:**

```
using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core;

public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm() => InitializeComponent();

    protected override async void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        webView2.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted += OnCoreWebView2InitializationCompleted;
        var env = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(null, null, null);
        await webView2.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(env);
        webView2.Source = new Uri("https://www.somesite.com");
    }

    private void OnCoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object sender, CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        webView2.CoreWebView2.NewWindowRequested += OnNewWindowRequested;
    }

    private void OnNewWindowRequested(object sender, CoreWebView2NewWindowRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Open the Uri requested in the current Window
        e.Handled = true;
        ((CoreWebView2)sender).Navigate(e.Uri);
    }
  
    // Or, if you want to handle Popup Windows using your own Form template
    // => Note that it's the same event handler as above, pick one, not both!
    private void OnNewWindowRequested(object sender, CoreWebView2NewWindowRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Open the Uri requested in a new instance of the PopupWindow Form
        var deferral = e.GetDeferral();
        e.Handled = true;
        var popup = new PopupWindow(deferral, e);
        popup.Show();
    }
}
```

If you instead want to create a new Form that will show the popup, you need a Form template (it can be just a Form that contains a WebView2 Control) that receive the [CoreWebView2Deferral](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2newwindowrequestedeventargs.getdeferral) returned by [e.GetDeferral()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2newwindowrequestedeventargs.getdeferral).

In the initialization procedure of this Form check whether the `CoreWebView2Deferral` object is null. If it's not, complete the deferred event by calling its [Complete()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2deferral.complete) method.

Then subscribe to the `NewWindowRequested` event to perform the same action when a new Popup Window is requested (unless you want to block it).

Of course you can show these Forms inside a Tabbed Control, to generate a standard tabbed view, common in all WebBrowsers.

Sample **`PopupWindow` Form**:

```
using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class PopupWindow : Form
{
    public PopupWindow() => InitializeComponent();
    public PopupWindow(CoreWebView2Deferral deferral, CoreWebView2NewWindowRequestedEventArgs args) 
        : this() {
        Core2Deferral = deferral;
        NewWindowArgs = args;
    }

    protected virtual CoreWebView2Deferral Core2Deferral { get; private set; }
    protected virtual CoreWebView2NewWindowRequestedEventArgs NewWindowArgs { get; private set; }

    protected async override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        webView2.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted += OnCoreWebView2InitializationCompleted;

        var env = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(null, null, null);
        await webView2.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(env);
    }

    private void OnCoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object sender, CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        webView2.CoreWebView2.Settings.AreDefaultContextMenusEnabled = true;
        if (Core2Deferral != null) {
            NewWindowArgs.NewWindow = webView2.CoreWebView2;
            Core2Deferral.Complete();
        }
        webView2.CoreWebView2.NewWindowRequested += OnNewWindowRequested;
    }

    private void OnNewWindowRequested(object sender, CoreWebView2NewWindowRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        var popup = new PopupWindow(e.GetDeferral(), e);
        popup.Show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about making it works **like real web browsers.** Simply, opens in an new Tab. Just with a **few lines of codes ;)**

At first, create a new class which inherits from **WebView2** and include a **TabControl** field inside it:

```
internal class WebViewInTab:WebView2
{
    TabControl tabCtrl;

    public WebViewInTab(TabControl tabCtrl) :base()
        {
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill; // necessary for showing 
            this.tabCtrl = tabCtrl; // for adding new TabPage controls
            CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted += WebViewInTab_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted;
        }
```

Then, you'll use this **custom webview2** to create new webview2 objects every time **CoreWebView2.NewWindowRequested** event is raised. So to handle the event:

```
private void WebViewInTab_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object? sender, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    CoreWebView2.NewWindowRequested += CoreWebView2_NewWindowRequested; // This is the man
    CoreWebView2.DocumentTitleChanged += CoreWebView2_DocumentTitleChanged; // Just cosmetic code
}
```

After that, you'll handle the new window by yourself, i.e. , Just add a new **TabPage** control with our **custom webview2** to the **TabControl** TabPages collection. Of course, not forgeting the **Uri** from handler arg.

```
private void CoreWebView2_NewWindowRequested(object? sender, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2NewWindowRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true; // let the default new window 

        TabPage tpage = new TabPage(); // boy

        tpage.Controls.Add(new WebViewInTab(tabCtrl) { Source = new Uri(e.Uri)}); // toy

        tabCtrl.TabPages.Add(tpage); // daddy
        tabCtrl.SelectedTab = tpage; // user expectation
    }

//Just cosmetic code
private void CoreWebView2_DocumentTitleChanged(object? sender, object e)
    {
        int last = tabCtrl.TabPages.Count - 1;
        tabCtrl.TabPages[last].Text = CoreWebView2.DocumentTitle
    }
}
```

Finally, :) start the **recursion-ready** operation in the main app form constructor.

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string uriAdd = "https://www.w3schools.com/";
            tabControl1.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(new WebViewInTab(tabControl1) { Source = new Uri(uriAdd) });
        }
```