# How can I interact with parallel page loaded from WebView2?

Tags: vb.net, window, webview2

I have written some `VB.Net` code using `WebView2` control to try to download a PDF file from a specific magazine.

My `VB.Net` code is following

```
Imports Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Call InitializeAsync()
    End Sub

    Async Sub InitializeAsync()
        Await wv.EnsureCoreWebView2Async()
        wv.CoreWebView2.Navigate("https://journal.cinetelerevue.sudinfo.be")
    End Sub

    Private Sub wv_NavigationCompleted(sender As Object, e As CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs) Handles wv.NavigationCompleted
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        Call ClickOnPdfButton()
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    End Sub

    Async Sub ClickOnPdfButton()
        Dim sButtonCmd = "document.getElementById('readPdfBtn').click();"
        Dim task = Await wv.ExecuteScriptAsync(sButtonCmd)
    End Sub

End Class
```

The first `Navigate()` method display correctly requested URL.

The Javascript `document.getElementById('readPdfBtn').click();` method works also correclty. It open a **NEW** window because Javascript code linked to `click()` method do following action

```
var e = window.open("","pdf_view");
```

When program has run, I obtain following result

[image]

I have painted a red circle around `PDF` button in first Window.

My problem is that I need to continue to click on another `PDF` button contained in new Window to initiate PDF download.

**How can I access it using `wv` WebView2 variable ?**

In tasks manager, I can see that new Windows is attached to `Extract-PDF-From-Web` application that is the name of my `VB.Net` application.

[image]

Comment: [e.NewWindow = (CoreWebView2)sender still results in a separate instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68790332/7444103) (read the notes in code)

Comment: this answer can help but I wait an answer for VB.Net not for C# where events are defined with another technique.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, I have added an event handler in `wv.NavigationCompleted` event in which I have changed `e.NewWindow` property.

I have also try to set `URI` but without success.

The full `VB.Net` solution that works using Visual Studio 2022 is following

```
Imports Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Call InitializeAsync()
    End Sub

    Async Sub InitializeAsync()
        Await wv.EnsureCoreWebView2Async()
        wv.CoreWebView2.Navigate("https://journal.cinetelerevue.sudinfo.be")
    End Sub

    Public Sub NewWindowRequested(sender As Object, e As CoreWebView2NewWindowRequestedEventArgs)
        e.Handled = True
        Dim cwv As CoreWebView2 = sender
        e.NewWindow = cwv
    End Sub

    Private Sub wv_NavigationCompleted(sender As Object, e As CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs) Handles wv.NavigationCompleted
        AddHandler wv.CoreWebView2.NewWindowRequested, AddressOf Me.NewWindowRequested
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        Call ClickOnPdfButton()
    End Sub

    Async Sub ClickOnPdfButton()
        Dim sButtonCmd = "document.getElementById('readPdfBtn').click();"
        Dim task = Await wv.ExecuteScriptAsync(sButtonCmd)
    End Sub

End Class
```

After running this code, I obtain following result

[image]