# Prevent new window opening on WebView2

Tags: vb.net, winforms, .net-6.0, webview2

I need to open a webpage and after I press the log in button, a new edge window is being opened.
I want to prevent it and I find a lot of questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68782495/e-newwindow-corewebview2sender-still-results-in-a-separate-instance)
and converting the code in vb.net I'm getting something like

```
Imports Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core
Imports Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms
Public Class Form1

    Private Async Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        MyBase.OnLoad(e)
        WebView21.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted += AddressOf OnCoreWebView2InitializationCompleted
        Dim env = Await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)
        Await WebView21.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(env)
        WebView21.Source = New Uri("https://www.somesite.com")
    End Sub
    Private Sub OnCoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs)
        WebView21.CoreWebView2.NewWindowRequested += AddressOf OnNewWindowRequested
    End Sub

    Private Sub OnNewWindowRequested(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As CoreWebView2NewWindowRequestedEventArgs)
        e.Handled = True
        (CType(sender, CoreWebView2)).Navigate(e.Uri)
    End Sub
End Class
```

but Im getting errors, maybe due to the conversion ( Im using a c# to vb.net online tool)

> Description
> Syntax error.

> 'Public Event NewWindowRequested As EventHandler(Of CoreWebView2NewWindowRequestedEventArgs)' is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event.

> 'Public Event CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted As EventHandler(Of CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs)' is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event.

I've also tried [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66191200/how-to-prevent-webview2edge-based-to-open-a-new-window) and I am not getting any error, but in the moment I click in the login button, no new page is being opened or loaded.
Is there a fix to it? Thanks

Comment: `AddHandler WebView21.CoreWebView2.NewWindowRequested, AddressOf OnNewWindowRequested` etc.

Comment: in which part of my code am i supposed to add it Jimi?

Comment: Add it? You're supposed to replace the C# syntax (`[Object].Event += [Delegate]`) with the VB.NET syntax (`AddHandler [Object].Event, AddressOf [Delegate]`)

Comment: Grazie :) I change them both. What about this 
    (CType(sender, CoreWebView2)).Navigate(e.Uri) ?
it says syntax err

Comment: `DirectCast(sender, CoreWebView2).Navigate(e.Uri)`

Comment: Im getting at debug a System.StackOverflowException error on MyBase.OnLoad(e) :\

Comment: Solved just commenting it :)))))
Grazie Jimi!!!!

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73846538/10024425