# Open a popup link on new tab with webview2 in winforms c# programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms, webview2

I added tabcontrol inside of that webview let consider this as wv1 I open a pop link on this webview this popup link will open on the new tab and new webview2

Click below to refer img
[after run the code wv1 on tab2 image try it button popup link will open on new webview2 inside of a new tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaC67.png)

Code:

```
namespace WindowsBrowserApplication
{
    public partial class WindowsWebView : Form
    {
        public WindowsWebView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void WindowsWebView_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InitBrowser();
        }

        private async Task Initizated()
        {
            await WebView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);
        }

        public async void InitBrowser()
        {
            await Initizated();
            WebView.CoreWebView2.Navigate("https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_open");
            WebView.CoreWebView2.NewWindowRequested += CoreWebView2_NewWindowRequested;
        }

        public async void InitBrowserTab()
        {
            await Initizated();
        }
        private void CoreWebView2_NewWindowRequested(object sender, CoreWebView2NewWindowRequestedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;

            InitBrowserTab();
            TabPage tpage = new TabPage();

            var web = new WebView2();
            tpage.Controls.Add(web);
            tabControl.TabPages.Add(tpage);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the notes here: [e.NewWindow = (CoreWebView2)sender still results in a separate instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68790332/7444103) and the comments in code, so you don't duplicate the an event handler by mistake

Comment: Can you elaborate on what your actual question is here?

Comment: What I need to do for open pop up event to new tab included with new webview2

Answer (score 1):

**Like real web browsers.**

At first, create a new class which inherits from **WebView2** and include a **TabControl** field inside it:

```
internal class WebViewInTab:WebView2
{
    TabControl tabCtrl;

    public WebViewInTab(TabControl tabCtrl) :base()
        {
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill; // necessary for showing 
            this.tabCtrl = tabCtrl; // for adding new TabPage controls
            CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted += WebViewInTab_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted;
        }
    .
    .
    .
```

Then, you'll use this **custom webview2** to create new webview2 objects every time **CoreWebView2.NewWindowRequested** event is raised. So to handle the event:

```
private void WebViewInTab_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object sender, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    CoreWebView2.NewWindowRequested += CoreWebView2_NewWindowRequested; // This is the man
    CoreWebView2.DocumentTitleChanged += CoreWebView2_DocumentTitleChanged; // Just cosmetic code
}
```

After that, Just add a new **TabPage** control with our **custom webview2** to the **TabControl** TabPages collection. Of course, not forgeting the **Uri** from handler arg.

```
private void CoreWebView2_NewWindowRequested(object sender, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2NewWindowRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true; // let the default new window 

        TabPage tpage = new TabPage(); // boy

        tpage.Controls.Add(new WebViewInTab(tabCtrl) { Source = new Uri(e.Uri)}); // toy

        tabCtrl.TabPages.Add(tpage); // daddy
        tabCtrl.SelectedTab = tpage; // user expectation
    }

//Just cosmetic code
private void CoreWebView2_DocumentTitleChanged(object sender, object e)
    {
        int last = tabCtrl.TabPages.Count - 1;
        tabCtrl.TabPages[last].Text = CoreWebView2.DocumentTitle;
    }
}
```

Finally, :) start the **recursion-ready** operation in the main app form constructor.

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string uriAdd = "https://www.w3schools.com/";
            tabControl1.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(new WebViewInTab(tabControl1) { Source = new Uri(uriAdd) });
        }
```